# Randomly swap 2 elements of array with another 2 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of team members and a list of 2 substitutes:
`team` = Samson, Max, Rowan, Flynn, Jack
`subs` = Struan, Harry

I need to randomly swap the 2 `subs` into the team. I'm getting stuck because I need to ensure that only these 2 elements are swapped and that both are swapped in. I tried just looping through the `subs` array and randomly swapping each element with an element from the `team` array, but too frequently it swapped Struan with Max and then Harry with Struan, so that in the end Struan was still in the `subs` array and not in the `team`.

So: I need to exclusively swap the 2 elements in the `sub` array with random elements from the `team` array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with this function. Give the function current team and substitudes and get new team with random substitution done.

```js
const team = ['Samson', 'Max', 'Rowan', 'Flynn', 'Jack']
const subs = ['Struan', 'Harry']

const substitudePlayers = (team, subs) => {
  const newTeam = [...team]
  // get 2 random numbers which are less than team members count
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max-1);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  // 2 random numbers
  let num1 = getRandomInt(0, team.length)
  let num2 = getRandomInt(0, team.length)
  
  // make sure that numbers are different
  while(num2 === num1) num2++
  
  // substitude
  newTeam[num1]=subs[0]
  newTeam[num2]=subs[1]
  return newTeam
}

const substitudedTeam = substitudePlayers(team, subs);

console.log(substitudedTeam)
```

Comment: This got me there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function getRandomItem () {
   let randomItem = team[Math.floor(Math.random()*team.length)];
   if(subs.indexOf(randomItem)<0){
      return randomItem;
   } else {
      return getRandomItem();
   }
}

subs.forEach((item,i)=>{
   subs.splice(i,1,getRandomItem());
}
```